# Change django haystack search view based on user profile element

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

So, I've read around here and elsewhere, and I've seen people load different html templates, or do something in the template itself to change what is displayed, but what I am wanting to do is load a different view or form based on an element in the user profile.

My urls.py looks something like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', MySearchView(
        searchqueryset=sqs,
        form_class=BasicPropertySearchForm
    ), name="haystack_search"),
)
```

I can set the line

```
form_class=
```

to either BasicPropertySearchForm or PaidPropertySearchForm manually, and the corresponding search page will load properly and function, no problem.

But what I'd like to do is have the form_class automated so it loads BasicPropertySearchForm or PaidPropertySearchForm based on the user profile.

I tried accomplishing this with request.user.get_profile() in the view like this:

```
class MySearchView(SearchView):
#extends the default haystack SearchView
    def which_view(self):
        if self.request.user.get_profile().is_paid:
            return PaidPropertySearchForm
        else:
            return BasicPropertySearchForm
```

and changing

```
form_class=MySearchView().which_view
```

but that results in the error

```
which_view() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)
```

I have tried many other variations including using a method that's not within a class in the views.py, doing the if statment in the urls.py (which i realized wouldn't work since I'm imagining I have to access the request.user.get_profile() from withing a view)...

I also tried doing this:

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^$', 'property_listings.views.search_views', name="haystack_search"),
)
```

and views.py:

```
def search_views(request, *args, **kwargs):

    sqs = SearchQuerySet().all

    if request.user.get_profile().is_paid:
        return SearchView(
            searchqueryset=sqs,
            form_class=PaidPropertySearchForm
        )(request, *args, **kwargs)
    else: 
        return SearchView(
            searchqueryset=sqs,
            form_class=BasicPropertySearchForm
        )(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

but then my forms gave me all sorts of errors about stuff not being defined, like self.searchqueryset.all() all does not exist for that or something or another..

Any help would be appreciated, I must've read 50 different blogs, doc pages, stack overflow posts, etc. over the last few days and I'm banging my head against a wall here..